# Angularjs Mobile UI ngRoute injection error

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm having problem with ngRoute injection...
I have the file angular-route.min.js inclueded in the right path but still getting [this error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ParkPlanner&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:unpr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.17%2F$injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3D%2524stateProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:36:145%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:34:227)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.d%20%5Bas%20invoke%5D%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:34:444)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:33:326%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Array.forEach%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:7:280)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:33:139)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ec%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmangular%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:36:252)

Here is javascript code:

```
 (function() {

 var app = angular.module('ParkPlanner', ['mobile-angular-ui', 'ngRoute']);

  app.config (['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

 .state('home', {
   url: '/home',
   templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
 })

 .state('results', {
   url: '/results',
   templateUrl: 'pages/results.html'
 });

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

 }]);

})();
```

Here is the HTML head:

```
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/mobile-angular-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Any idea what I'm missing?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My Friend yo should put also route.min.js.map and , 
try importing "$routeProvider" instead of "$urlRouterProvider"  , lets give a try .

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
I've added:
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js.map"></script>
and replaced urlRouterProvider with routeProvider...
Still the same error and Unexpected token < inside angular-route.min.js.map

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to configure states with ng-router. That is not supported. You should configure routes like this in ng-router:

```
.when('/home', {
   templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'
 })
```

Alternatively, you should add dependency to angular-ui-router like this:

```
var app = angular.module('ParkPlanner', ['mobile-angular-ui', 'ui.router']);
app.config (['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider

      .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: 'pages/home.html'

      //And so on....
 })
})();
```